# How to show report with JasperReports API

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using `NetBeans 7` and developing java database application. For the reporting purpose I have installed the `iReport 4` plug-in in `NetBeans 7` and designed the very simple report of my application. How can I call the report through a button call.

**Few days later of this question what i have done is:**

I downloaded the JAR file and added it to the Netbeans after that i did the following coding in a button but as i click the button it gives this error:

> ```
> 'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"     java.lang.Error:'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException'
> ```

**And this is is the code which i have done on a button event click:**

```
try {
    String reportName = "prisonersdbv1/reports/newReport.jasper";
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/APD", "root", "khan");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, new HashMap(), conn);
    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
    jv.setVisible(true);
} catch (JRException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PrisonersDBv1View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PrisonersDBv1View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PrisonersDBv1View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex)
}
```

Comment: *"Your help will be highly appreciated."*  A question, a stack trace & an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) will be highly helpful.

Comment: You should post the code. The `iReport` is GUI designer for building report's templates.

Comment: After i installed the plug-in i did this(Nebeans-->file menu-->new file-->ireport wizard) to create the report so I haven't done any coding in designing my report.

Comment: iReport is a visual designer for the JasperReports reporting library. The NetBeans plugin does not generate the actual **code** to display such a report. Read (at least) through the [JasperReports Tutorial](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish//jasperreportswebsite/JR%20Website/jasperreports_tutorial.html) to get an idea about the workflow and the API's.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing report with help of [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) you can use the ***[net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JasperViewer.html)*** class.

The sample of using:

```
JasperViewer.viewReport("sampleReport.jrprint", false, true, locale);
```

You can find the full sample of using ***`JasperViewer`*** in `$jasperreports$\demo\samples\i18n` folder from the `JasperReports` distribution package.

Comment: As you have mentioned i have downloaded the JAR file and added it to the Netbeans after that i did the following coding in a button but as i click the button it gives this error: 'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error:<br /> 'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException'<br />
**the next comment is the code which i have done on a button event click:**<br />

Comment: I dont know how to comment/post the code it is kind of 50 chracters and here it couldn't post, any idea?...

Comment: You can edit your question or even better you should post the new question